# Assambly language indirect address

Tags: assembly

im new in assamble lang.. but i gut a question conserning ono of the difficult topics in assamb...
ok 
example:

```
mov [bx],9h  ;9h into segment in memory with value 9h
mov ax,[bx]  ;i get what is pointed to memory in bx 9h
```

ok the problem here is that in this case the return is

`ax` == `ah`=20 `al`=09 right i got the value 9h but why 20 in `ah`

if i do this:

```
mov word ptr [bx],9h
mov ax ,[bx]
```

ok......`ah`=00 `al`=09

also ok like this:

```
mov word ptr [bx],9h
mov al ,[bx]
```

why the 20 in `ah`.

Answer (score 0):

The value `9h` fits in a byte, so the instruction `mov [bx],9h` is the same as `mov byte ptr [bx],9h`. It will put the value `09h` in the byte that `bx` is pointing to.

When you read the value into `ax` that is a word operation, as `ax` is a word register. It will get the value `09h` that you put in memory, but also the value in the following byte. In this case that value happened to be `20h`.

When you use `mov word ptr [bx],9h` it's a word operation, and the value `9h` is expanded to a word (`0009h`). It will be stored as the two bytes `09h` and `00h` in memory.

When you use `mov al ,[bx]` it's a byte operation as `al` is a byte register, so it will only read the byte that you stored.

Comment: frind thanks but now i also proved mov byte ptr [bx],9h then mov ax,[bx] the same ah20 al 09 any way you are right.

Comment: yes is like that 9 is a byte in ax=16bits when it return from memory maybe there was lets suppose in memory the address 1000 there was 09 20. im ok?